# Prolog with Constrains advice

Tags: prolog

I am trying to solve a simple jigsaw puzzle, where each side of a piece as either an orifice or a salience, and all pieces must fit each other
  So far I have this representing each piece, the first number represents the id and the numbers in the array represent if it has an orifice(0) our salience(1) clockwise starting from the left

```
peca(1,[0,1,1,1]).
peca(2,[0,0,1,0]).
peca(3,[1,0,0,0]).
peca(4,[0,1,0,1]).
peca(5,[1,1,1,1]).
peca(6,[0,0,0,1]).
peca(7,[1,1,0,1]).
peca(8,[0,0,1,1]).
peca(9,[1,1,1,0]).
peca(10,[1,0,1,1]).
peca(11,[1,1,0,0]).
peca(12,[0,1,0,0]).
```

This are all the constrains I made, just Imagine an 4x3 puzzle where each row as 4 elements. So the bottom of the top left one must fit with the top of the piece below it,etc...

```
encaixaOrientacao(Vars,0):-
                Vars#=N,
                    peca(N,[L,U,R,D]),
                peca(N+1,[NL,NU,NR,ND]),
                R+NL#=1,
                peca(N+1,[L,U,R,D]),
                peca(N+2,[NL,NU,NR,ND]),
                    R+NL#=1,
                peca(N+2,[L,U,R,D]),
                peca(N+3,[NL,NU,NR,ND]),
                R+NL#=1,
                peca(N,[L,U,R,D]),
                peca(N+4,[NL,NU,NR,ND]),
                    D+NU#=1,
                peca(N+1,[L,U,R,D]),
                peca(N+5,[NL,NU,NR,ND]),
                D+NU#=1,
                peca(N+2,[L,U,R,D]),
                peca(N+6,[NL,NU,NR,ND]),
                D+NU#=1,
                peca(N+3,[L,U,R,D]),
                peca(N+7,[NL,NU,NR,ND]),
                D+NU#=1,
                peca(N+4,[L,U,R,D]),
                peca(N+5,[NL,NU,NR,ND]),
                R+NL#=1,
                peca(N+5,[L,U,R,D]),
                    peca(N+6,[NL,NU,NR,ND]),
                R+NL#=1,
                peca(N+6,[L,U,R,D]),
                peca(N+7,[NL,NU,NR,ND]),
                R+NL#=1,
                peca(N+4,[L,U,R,D]),
                peca(N+8,[NL,NU,NR,ND]),
                D+NU#=1,
                peca(N+5,[L,U,R,D]),
                peca(N+9,[NL,NU,NR,ND]),
                D+NU#=1,
                peca(N+6,[L,U,R,D]),
                peca(N+10,[NL,NU,NR,ND]),
                D+NU#=1,
                peca(N+7,[L,U,R,D]),
                peca(N+11,[NL,NU,NR,ND]),
                D+NU#=1,
                peca(N+8,[L,U,R,D]),
                peca(N+9,[NL,NU,NR,ND]),
                R+NL#=1,
                peca(N+9,[L,U,R,D]),
                peca(N+10,[NL,NU,NR,ND]),
                R+NL#=1,
                peca(N+10,[L,U,R,D]),
                peca(N+11,[NL,NU,NR,ND]),
                R+NL#=1.
```

This is the main, ignore the O for now since I still haven't implemented it

```
  main(Vars):-
        read(O),
        length(Vars,12),
        domain(Vars,1,12),
        all_distinct(Vars),

        %ainda nao funciona o encaixaOrientacao
        encaixaOrientacao(Vars,O),

        labeling([],Vars).
```

I have done this so, but I am lost to what to do next, I really need some help to make this work. So anykind of advice would be welcome

The puzzle itself is this one http://www.jaapsch.net/puzzles/rapids.htm Though I still haven't implemented anything regarding the "borders" and orientation

Comment: It's still on your first question topic, no need to create another one imho.

Comment: Well since my first question was a couple of new days ago, I thought it would be already lost amongst all new questions that came up. I don't really use this website very often.

Answer (score 0):

As Mog said in his comment, it's still the same question, so expect this to be closed.

Two things, though: I don't think your predicate `encaixaOrientacao/2` will work, since you access specific pieces by calling `peca/2` and constrain some variables, thereby stating which piece goes where. There are also several other problems with your implementation:

- you probably wanted to express something like `peca(Vars[N+1], ...)` when you wrote `peca(N+1, ...)`. This doesn't work in Prolog.
- you are reusing the `L,U,R,D,NL,NU,NR,ND` variables. This means that they will have the same values in every call of `peca/2`. This won't work.

Furthermore, your predicate `peca/2` is just a regular predicate, not a constraint. That means that when you call `encaixaOrientacao/2`, any call to `peca/2` will directly retrieve some fact from your database, and your constraints `X+Y #= 1` will check if it is a possible neighbour. While this would work in principle (modulo the problems I pointed out above), this wouldn't be Constraint Programming, since the constraints would be used only after the next piece was selected. Your model should distinguish between fields and pieces, and the `X+Y #= 1` constraints would then restrict the fields, not the pieces.

The next step then would be to express a constraint "if piece N is at position X, then the edges of that field have properties P", and "if the edges of field X have properties P, then it can't contain piece N" (the latter is what was omitted from my answer to your first question, but what would make the solution proper Constraint Programming instead of using the constraints merely as tests).

Comment: Can you give me an example of how I exactly should constrain an field in the context of this problem?

Comment: I put my code here: http://pastebin.com/weztX3xb. Note that I wrote it in ECLiPSe, although I tried to make it more general. You may not have all language elements available in Sicstus, but it should be easy to find the equivalent constructs. For the variables that encode which field contains which piece, I used a two-dimensional array, corresponding two your list `Vars`. For the variables that encode the edges, I used a three-dimensional array. (arrays are just terms of terms, but I can access an element directly using `arg/3`)

Comment: Thanks, that is quite helpfull. Though I believe SICStus has no equivalent of Demon and Suspend

Comment: Sicstus allows the user to define constraints, just like ECLiPSe does with `suspend`. I found this via Google: http://www.sics.se/sicstus/docs/4.2.0/html/sicstus/The-Global-Constraint-Programming-Interface.html#The-Global-Constraint-Programming-Interface You should be able to work out the rest.